# Sidebars are no longer working

Tags: sidebar

I am trying to figure out why my sidebar is no longer working. I tried reinstalling my theme, disabling all of my plugins, and uploading a fresh version of widgets.php, with no luck.

I am using the Photogram theme, but the problem doesn't go away if I change to a different theme.

Here is what I see when I go to my widgets page:

[image: Widgets page]

[image: Zoom in of the area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### uploading a fresh version of widgets.php

which widgets.php?

I guess you updated **wp-admin/includes/widgets.php**?

you actually need to update **wp-includes/widgets.php** where dynamic_sidebar function defined in.

Comment: Wonderful! Based on the error message I updated wp-admin/includes/widgets.php. This worked great. Grazie!